# Bucket no longer showing result by default when assigning a default bucket view

Tags: buckets

As soon as a set a default bucket view (for instance the table view) the bucket won't show any results or facets anymore when you open it. You have to press the search button explicitly. This is a unwanted extra click I would like to avoid.

Why is this and is there a way to make it show the results when you open the bucket?

When I open a bucket with a default view I see this (note that now you have to press the search button for results to show up):
[image]

Without a default view I see this (note how the result appear immediately):
[image]

Iam using sitecore 9.2.

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots or add some more details here for what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat added some screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think this is a bug in Sitecore and I will suggest you to reach to support team for this, but I found a workaround for this. You need to update the `ItemBucket.utils.js` file for this -

> \sitecore\shell\Applications\Buckets\Scripts\ItemBucket.utils.js

In this file, you need to update few lines in `establishViews` function, a hack is to trigger the click event based on the current view by adding a line- `$j("#" + window.CurrentView).trigger("click");`-

```
 if (window.CurrentView && window.CurrentView !== "list") {
            $j("#views a").removeClass("active");
            $j("#" + window.CurrentView).trigger("click");
            $j("#" + window.CurrentView).addClass("active");
        }
```

in additional, there one more line need to update for showing the active view after the click in the same function from `$j("#" + filter.ID).addClass("active");` to `$j("#" + filter.ViewName).addClass("active");`-

```
$j.each(views, function (index, filter) {
            $j("#" + filter.ViewName).click(function () {
                CurrentView = filter.ViewName;
                a.find(".sb_up").click();
                pageNumber = 0;

                $j.each(defaultViews, function (subIndex, subfilter) {
                    $j("." + subfilter).removeClass("active");
                });
                $j("#" + filter.ViewName).addClass("active");
                $j('.content').css({ 'opacity': 1.0 });
                $j("#ajaxBusy").css({ display: "block" });
                var n = buildQuery();
                runQuery(n, pageNumber, h, OnSearchRunFail);
                runFacet(n, pageNumber, meme, OnSearchRunFail);

                $j(".navAlpha").html("");
                $j(".slide-out-div").html("").prepend(LoadGifText);
                $j("#ajaxBusyFacet").css({
                    display: "none",
                    margin: "0px auto",
                    width: "44px"
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is not relevant to my question and as you can see in the screenshots I already have a persistent filter.... I just want the results to show up when opening the bucket which has nothing to do with these filters you can configure.

Comment: This is a workaround for your problem, generally, if you don't have any filter you can simply put your start location in `Default Bucket Query` and it will work. If you are saying this is not working for you, it means you have a different problem.

Comment: This only works if you haven't set a default view.

Comment: I have changed my answer, I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: The view is now active but I still dont see any results

Comment: Did you add this  $j("#" + window.CurrentView).trigger("click") as well? I have tested this and it was working.

Comment: it only works when you switch between views I noticed but not on the first time you open the bucket

Comment: @Barsonax with these changes and adding Default Bucket Query, everything is working fine, I have tested this with Sitecore 9.2, Could you please test after clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Clearing the browser cache makes it work thanks!